# Going back a page goes back to 1st page with new-nav update

Tags: bug, new-nav

I was searching questions on SO, and I was on about the 3rd page when I clicked on a question. After reading the question and realizing I had no answer, I tried to go back to where I was in the list of questions by clicking the back arrow in my browser. Before the new-navigation update I could do this, but after the update when I tried going back to my old position in the question list, I was redirected all the way to the top of the first page. I think this is a bug of sorts, and it gets quite annoying trying to find my old place every time I visit a post. I am hoping somebody can fix it. Thanks!